# MySQL making search function won't work

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to build a search function into my site, which lets you find users based on their name or surname and then it will print all found names. Problem is, that I won't work at all. Can you guys help me?

EDIT: if I try to search something, it will always give me the answer that nothing was found.

The php code:

```
<?php
    $search = $_POST["search"];
    if(isset($search)) {
        $findname = "SELECT `name` FROM Account WHERE $search = `name` 
                    OR SELECT `name` FROM `Account` WHERE $search = `surname` 
                    OR SELECT `name` FROM `Account` 
                    WHERE $search = `name` . `surname` 
                    OR SELECT `name` FROM `Account` WHERE $search = `name` . `surnameprefix` . `surname`";

        $findsurname = "SELECT `surname` from Account WHERE $search = `name` 
                        OR SELECT `surname` FROM `Account` WHERE $search = `surname` 
                        OR SELECT `surname` FROM `Account` WHERE $search = `name` . `surname` 
                        OR SELECT `surname` FROM `Account` WHERE $search = `name` . `surnameprefix` . `surname`";

        $result2 = mysql_query($findsurname);
        $result1 = mysql_query($findname);
            if($result1 == false && $result2 == false) {
                echo '<div id="searchresult"><h1>People found:</h1> <p>No one was found...</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<div id="searchresult">
                        <h1>People found:</h1>
                        <table id="searchtable">
                            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
                                <tr id="searchtablerow">
                                    <td> $findname ' . '$findsurname</td>
                                    <td><img src="standard-profile-square.jpg" id="searchpicture"></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                    </div>';
            }
        }
?>
```

The html form code:

```
    <div id="searchform">
        <h1>Search friends:</h1>
        <form name="searchform" method="post" action ="searchlink.php">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autofocus placeholder="e.g. John Smith..."></input> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submitsearch" value="Search" id="searchbutton"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Thank you guys in advance for helping me!

Yours sincerely,
Unheil

Comment: You're looking to do a mysql subquery https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html

Comment: what does not work? any error messages? what is shown?

Comment: Your complete queries seems to be nonesense ;)

Comment: and if `$search` is a string, it needs to be quoted, which seems to be the case. Using `mysql_error()` and php's error reporting would have been of help.

Comment: your last echo is too long. The php instructions for outputting your result are not interpreted but outputted. `echo '<div id="searchresult">... id="searchtable">';  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ echo '..';}`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Start by using `WHERE name = $search` also check the rest of your query for this little mistake

Comment: This is worth a couple of kittens more ^^ -> $findname = "SELECT `name` FROM Account WHERE $search = `name` OR SELECT ..... ";

Answer (score 0):

Your last echo is too long. The php instructions for outputting your result are not interpreted but outputted.

```
<?php
} else {
  echo '<div id="searchresult">
  <h1>People found:</h1>
  <table id="searchtable">';
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo '<tr id="searchtablerow">
        <td> '.$findname.' '.$findsurname.'</td>
        <td><img src="standard-profile-square.jpg" id="searchpicture"></td>
      </tr>';
  }
  echo '</table></div>';
}
?>
```

And if you use ' for Strings, you have to concat your variables into it.

Comment: I think you will find there is a lot more wrong that that, if you look closer

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code. The SQL statements are wrong. The two statements basically do the same thing 
except they return a different column.

The SELECTs in the where clause are nonsense. Instead, in the where clause you should just add more qualifiers, not select statements.

In a SQL statement, you use PHP concatenation, which doesn't work in SQL.
The PHP code has many syntax and logic errors. You are using the mysql functions instead of the mysqli functions. 
You never open a connection to the database.

The list of problems in the code go on and on.

Here's some code that should work and get you closer to what you want.

```
<?php
    $host = 'your host name';
    $user = 'your db user name';
    $password = 'your db user name';
    $db_name = 'your db name';
    $search = $_POST["search"];
    if(isset($search)) {
        $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
        $wild_search = "%".$search."%";
        $findname = "SELECT `name`,`surname`
        FROM `Account` 
        WHERE `name` LIKE '".$wild_search."'
            OR `surname` LIKE '".$wild_search."'
            OR CONCAT(`name`, `surname`) LIKE '".$wild_search."'
            OR CONCAT(`name`, `surnameprefix`, `surname`) LIKE '".$wild_search."';";
        $query = mysqli_query($db,$findname);
        $results = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

        if($result) {
            echo "<div id='searchresult'>\n";
            echo "<h1>People Found</h1>\n";
            echo "<table id='searchresult'>\n";
            foreach($result as $rowno => $row) {
                echo "<tr class='searchtablerow'>\n";
                echo "<td>".$row['name'].", ".$row['surname']."</td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<div id='searchresult'><h1>People Found:</h1>\n";
            echo "<p>No one was found.</p>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
    } else {
    }
?>
```

In phpAdmin, try the following test statement. Substitute a name you know exists in the table for "smith" in the example:

```
SELECT `name`,`surname`
    FROM `Account` 
    WHERE `name` LIKE '%smith%'
        OR `surname` LIKE '%smith%'
        OR CONCAT(`name`, `surname`) LIKE '%smith%'
        OR CONCAT(`name`, `surnameprefix`, `surname`) LIKE '%smith%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used your code to rewrite the search form. However, it still won't find anyone in my database. Every time I press that button, it says: No one was found... How is this possible? On other pages I have linked to my database and it works just fine.

Comment: @Unheil: I edited the answer above and added an example you can run in phpAdmin. Give that a try and see if it works there. If it does, then the problem is in the PHP code.